# symbol in ggplot facet strip text

Tags: r, ggplot2

I would like to put G*<sub>1</sub> into facet strip text. I can get the * and I can get G<sub>1</sub> but I can't get them at the same time. (The picture above isn't quite right still, since the 1 is too far out, [this](https://chart.googleapis.com/chart?cht=tx&chl=G_1%5E%5Cstar) is a bit better.) Here is a small example:

```
df<-data.frame(mu=rnorm(12,0,1), p=rnorm(12,0,1), alpha=as.factor(rep(1:4,each=3)))

#This won't run
ggplot(df)+
  geom_point(aes(x=mu,y=p))+
  facet_wrap(~alpha, labeller =label_bquote(Q*"*"*[.(alpha)]))

#This puts the star way too high
ggplot(df)+
  geom_point(aes(x=mu,y=p))+
  facet_wrap(~alpha, labeller =label_bquote(Q[.(alpha)]^paste("*")))

#This puts the star too far right
ggplot(df)+
  geom_point(aes(x=mu,y=p))+
  facet_wrap(~alpha, labeller =label_bquote(Q[.(alpha)]*"*"))

#This puts U+2605 instead of the star
ggplot(df)+
  geom_point(aes(x=mu,y=p))+
  facet_wrap(~alpha, labeller =label_bquote(Q[.(alpha)]^"\u2605"))
```

After reading the first comment I thought it might be the font, but I can get a star to display using:

```
df<-data.frame(mu=rnorm(12,0,1), p=rnorm(12,0,1), alpha=paste("\u2605",rep(1:4,each=3)))

ggplot(df)+
  geom_point(aes(x=mu,y=p))+
  facet_wrap(~alpha)
```

Comment: the final one looks pretty good on ubuntu (it shows a star)

Comment: This works for me: `facet_wrap(~alpha, labeller =label_bquote(Q[.(alpha)]^"*"))`

Answer (score 0):

Looks to me like this should work:

```
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(df)+
  geom_point(aes(x=mu,y=p))+
  facet_wrap(~alpha, labeller = label_bquote("Q"*"*"[.(alpha)]))
```

Comment: this puts the 1 way out in front.

Comment: Oh I understand, sorry I was looking at your first sentence to try to match.